# CnosDB drop table column fail in k8s

Tags: cnosdb

#### Describe the bug

Version: cnosdb 2.3.4, revision 508f669fb723daa5195f05e8b020ebf3f322064d
Mode: 3meta + 2tskv

```
public ❯ drop table t1;
Query took 0.004 seconds.
public ❯ create table t1(a bigint, b bigint);
Query took 0.006 seconds.
public ❯ ALTER TABLE t1 drop b;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"050014","error_message":"Unreachable"}

Stack backtrace:
   0: anyhow::error::<impl anyhow::Error>::msg
   1: anyhow::__private::format_err
   2: client::ctx::SessionContext::sql::{{closure}}
   3: client::exec::exec_and_print::{{closure}}
   4: client::exec::exec_from_repl::{{closure}}
   5: cnosdb_cli::main::{{closure}}
   6: cnosdb_cli::main
   7: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace
   8: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
   9: core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once
             at ./rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:287:13
  10: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at ./rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:487:40
  11: std::panicking::try
             at ./rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:451:19
  12: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at ./rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panic.rs:140:14
  13: std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}
             at ./rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:48
  14: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at ./rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:487:40
  15: std::panicking::try
             at ./rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:451:19
  16: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at ./rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panic.rs:140:14
  17: std::rt::lang_start_internal
             at ./rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:20
  18: main
  19: <unknown>
  20: __libc_start_main
  21: _start
```

#### To Reproduce

*No response*

#### Expected behavior

*No response*

#### Additional context

*No response*